# setting the y.domain with a function in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to set the max of the y.domain in a boxplot in d3.js to the 90% quantile of all the data.

My code is at http://bl.ocks.org/cgdnorth/7218544.

I would like to change `y.domain([min,max]);` to have the max equal to the 90th of all the data rather than the maximum point.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 has a [d3.quantile](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_quantile) function that takes a sorted array of numbers and a quantile specifier and returns the value from the array that corresponds to that quantile.  So in your case you'd use:

```
var ninetieth = d3.quantile(numbers, 0.9);
```

Comment: Nice solution! That's certainly more elegant than doing the indexing manually.

Comment: Thanks, you can see I use quantile below in the function `tenth()`. I am wondering what I should put in for your variable `numbers`.

Comment: There's a loop already for determining `min` and `max` that looks at the `mean` column.  Instead of calculating `max` just push every `mean` value into an array and then sort it.  That's the `numbers` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by sorting the array of all values and then indexing into it, something like

```
var values = [];
data.forEach(function(d) { values = values.concat(e); });
values.sort(d3.ascending);
var max = values[Math.round((values.length-1)*0.9)];
```